# Accessing beans in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a project with spring-config.xml I have something like this:

```xml
 <!-- Job & Stage status notification via email-->
    <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host" value="${smtp.host}"/>
        <property name="port" value="${smtp.port}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${smtp.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${smtp.password}"/>
        <property name="javaMailProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

In an existing class I have something like this:

```java
@Autowired
private StatusEmailSender emailSender;
```

This seems to work. When I put the same code snippet in my own classes, `emailSender` is null. I can't find any dependencies that I am missing. Any idea how to do this? My classes are in a separate module from the one in which this works. Any idea how I can tell Spring I want to use that bean?

Comment: What is the relationship between `StatusEmailSender` and `JavaMailSenderImpl`? It seems that something is missing you your post. I guess that you have your own bean named `StatusEmailSender` that probably calls `JavaMailSenderImpl` initialized using the XML.

Comment: Try to get paricular object from appContext.

Comment: Seems likely that it's a duplicate  of http://stackoverflow.com/q/19896870/1240557

Comment: id doesn't matches emailsender and mailsender how that can be autowired

Comment: Sorry, I pasted the wrong side of the xml. Anyway, emailSender is in the xml as well.

Answer (score 2):

It can happen if you directly creating objects with `new YourOwnClass()` for your class which have `emailSender` as a dependency.Spring injects dependencies only if 
dependent bean is created  by spring.